# is this the right way to do multiplication on pyspark?

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

pyspark newbie. Here is my code:

```
def sparkApp():
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
        .config("spark.sql.catalogImplementation", "hive") \
        .config("spark.executor.memory", "4g") \
        .config("spark.driver.memory", "16g") \
        .config("spark.executor.instances", "5") \
        .config("spark.executor.cores", "5") \
        .getOrCreate()
    return spark

def my_f(x, w):
 return np.array(x).dot(w).sum()

w = [1,2]
x = sparkApp().("select x1, x2 from my_table")
x.rdd.map(lambda row: my_f(row, w)
```

My questions are:
 1. I know this parallelizes the reading of x but will it parallelize the multiplication of x and w? if so, will it return the values in the same index as the input? if not, how can I run it parallel it?
 2. Do I broadcast w or pass it as a parameter?

Thank You

Comment: did you test the code if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach doesn't actually give a dot product. Instead, your answer simply returns (x1+x2)*w. It does use parallelism but isn't really efficient.

If you want to manually compute dot product, you can create a pair RDD containing elements of x and w. Something like [(x1, w1), (x2, w2)] and then parallelize the process of computing products for each element in the pair RDD and then adding up the result.

Last option is to use the dot function in the module [pyspark.ml.linalg](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/ml/linalg.html). If your vectors are accessed from spark dataframe/rdd/dataset, it should use parallelism offered by spark.